# Get element at a specific line

Tags: php, xml

I am working with the DOMDocument in PHP. I need to get the element at a specific line. I am not talking about the balise name but the element inside the balise at line for example 354.

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could read in the XML as a string, `explode` by `\n` or `\r\n`, and then get the contents of the resulting array at position 353.